# Create Multiple events on same time on each day/date between different start and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using Fullcalendar,I have to create an event on same time between start and end date. Here my start and end dates are different but I have to create event on each day/date between start and end date on same time.

I was not able to above scenario into code .
Below is my data in an array for creating events:

```
createEvent=[
{
    title: 'QuoteIT', 
    resourceId: '423759xxxx00517869', 
    start: '2023-09-08T15:00:00+05:30', 
    end: '2023-09-08T18:00:00+05:30', 
    woid: '423759xxxxxx0068101'
},
{
    title: 'Internal Company', 
    resourceId: '42375900xxxx517869', 
    start: '2023-09-15T14:00:00+05:30', 
    end: '2023-09-16T16:00:00+05:30', 
    woid: '423759xxxxxxx01220009'
}
]
```

here I'm creating events using below jquery code :

events:createEvent

Comment: If you upgrade to a newer version of fullCalendar (the latest is version 6) you can use the Recurring Events feature - check the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events

Comment: If you wish to stay with the old fullCalendar 3 for some reason though, look at the link in the blue box above for a solution. (It's unclear to me why you were unable to find this by searching yourself?)